# web-page form submission with a limited count

Tags: java, forms, jsp, jakarta-ee, html

I have been asked in a JAVA/JEE interview question about how would achieve the business logic for the following scenario

> To build a web-page which gets user data through a form (a registration form ) and a total of 11 submissions (users) makes 1 team and once there are a total of 4 such teams the page shouldn't allow anymore submits.

My answer was "We need an action class which receives data submitted through the form and will first check for entries made in DB (counter) incremented with each entry.The class will check the counter if equal to 11 - another counter is incremented to show team (number) in db. Once the team number in DB reaches 4  the action class should forward to another page and prevent further submissions"

is my logic correct here or are there any better alternatives?

Comment: I would say that there's only one problem: if you have 43 submissions, for the number 44 I could fire 10 threads that simulate doing the same request, which will be attended by 10 threads on server side, which will fire a race condition after some of them pass the validation of *less than 4 teams* and store more than 44 users.

Comment: so what should be the proper way?

Comment: I'm not sure if this has a specific answer. AFAIK, I would use a trigger in the user table on pre insert to check the number of rows currently inserted. If there are more than 4 teams, raise an exception, which will be handled by application. Another option would be synchronizing in the web application the code that searches and add the data, so no trigger is involved. But note that synchronization blocks make your application slower.

Answer (score 1):

You could put each submission into a queue.  Some process could pull the items off of the queue and put them into a db.  Once you get to 44 you stop processing items off of the queue and set some flag indicating that all teams are full.